# Using ArcGIS on OSX without paying a fortune

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I'm running macOS High Sierra on an Early 2015 MacBook Air. As I'm a student, I'm looking to run ArcGIS on my computer without paying a fortune for licenses and and virtual machines.

Thus, [as a related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313681/can-i-run-windows-10-on-my-macbook-air-via-bootcamp-without-paying-for-a-windows/313682?noredirect=1#comment398043_313682), I asked if you could install and run Windows 10 via bootcamp without paying for a Windows license. It seems you are permitted a trial run of windows 10 for 90-days

Can I use arcGIS during this trial period with Windows 10?

Also, someone in the other question recommended using WineBottle, does anyone know if WineBottle is capable of running ArcGIS on mac?

This is the URL they gave:

http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/

Comment: WIndows 10 on a MacBook Air is simply Windows 10. So long as it meets the minimum specs for running [ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/setup/arcgis-desktop-system-requirements.htm), it will function properly.

Comment: Who gave you the URL? Did they do it suggesting it would run ArcGis?

Comment: Also, in your scenario: have you considered edu-licenses and/or [**free software alternatives**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_GIS_software)? Adapting your tasks to the alternatives might be much more instructive for you (although admittedly not always an option)

Comment: I didn't give you a link, but that link is right. You can use WineBottler to make Windows bottles (Virtual C: Drives)  and run Windows applications at native speeds inside these bottles if WineHQ supports these apps. Unfortunately, according to [WineHQ App Database](https://appdb.winehq.org), arcGIS runs like garbage on WineHQ. You can still try and find out if this has changed yourself. If it has not, you are out of luck.

Comment: There are several questions in here. How to run arcGIS natively under macOS, how to run it under Windows, and something about licenses. Only the first one would be on-topic. Please edit your question to make it easier to understand what you are looking for.